# How to avoid coordinates shifting in upscaled images?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have a following image:

[image]

There're 4 violet keypoints in the corners of the yellow area.

1. top left

[image]

2. top right

[image]

3. bottom right

[image]

4. bottom left

[image]

I upscale my image by factor 4 and then apply the same scaling to the coordinates of the keypoints. It's a simple scaling, not affine / perspective correction.

Here's my script:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


src_image = cv2.imread("source_image.png")
src_height, src_width = src_image.shape[0:2]
target_width = 968
target_height = 712
target_image = cv2.resize(src_image, (target_width, target_height))
points = [[20, 11], [11, 147], [223, 168], [232, 32]]
for p in points:
    p[0] = round(p[0] * target_width / src_width)
    p[1] = round(p[1] * target_height / src_height)
points = np.array(points)
points = points.reshape((-1, 1, 2))
cv2.polylines(target_image, [points], True, (255, 0, 255), 1)
cv2.imwrite("resized_image.png", target_image)
```

**What I expect to see** as a result of this script is the same image resized to a higher resolution (968 x 712) and all 4 keypoints still sticking to the corners of tha yellow area.

**What I get** as a result of this script is the same image resized to a higher resolution (968 x 712) and all 4 keypoint shifted top-left for some reason.

For instance, bottom right point is recessed inside of the yellow area:

[image]

I've connected all 4 points for better understanding of the shift:

[image]

The first question is what's the origin of the shift?
Both sides of the source image are even numbers and the scaling factor is a perfect integer number, so it's not an approximation / rounding issue.

The main question is how to overcome the problem and keep the keypoints in the very corners?

Comment: be exact about your transformations. resize considers the extreme corners of the corner pixels to be the corners of the picture. if you want a custom affine mapping, use warpAffine and a custom matrix

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz, the question is about simple resizing.. I've updated the question and added more screenshots.

Comment: `cv2.resize` does weird stuff for its coordinate system, as @ChristophRackwitz stated. This is exactly your problem. The origin is not the top-left pixel, it's the top-left corner of the little square centered on the top-left pixel.